# How to remove event added by JCEMediabox.Popup.Init()

Tags: jquery, joomla

I am using JCEMediabox plugin in Joomla. I want to remove the click event added by JCEMediabox   on load of the page which opens the popp JCEMediaBox.Popup.init(). 
I am trying to remove it using JCEMediaBox.Event.destroy(); but it is not removing the event. On click of link, it still opens the popup.

Comment: in my opinion if there were an option like this it should be like `Destroy` not `Distroy` make sure its not a typo

Comment: sorry, it was typo here. I had tried using JCEMediaBox.Event.destroy(); but it does not remove the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try simply overriding the click function? So whatever the event trigger is, try including a function like:

```
JCEMediabox.click(function(){ });
```

So an empty function that replaces whatever is previously set for the trigger to pop up the dialog.

Comment: Already tried it, as well as $('.jcepopup').unbind('click'); $('.jcepopup').off('click');$('.jcepopup').die('click'); but still not working

Comment: I also tried, JCEMediaBox.Event.remove(jQuery('.jcepopup'), 'click'); it still does not work